# Jquery: Use resize on an img without getting a generated div

Tags: jquery, html, image

My problem is a bit stupid but i can't seem to find any info on this.

Is it possible to use the .resize() function on an img object without it generating a div surrounding it?

Maybe this is a bit of a newbie question but this is my first jquery adventure in jqueryland so i'm still learning :)

Thanks in advance for the reactions.

Comment: Image resizing can be anything from simple to a real pain, depending on what you're doing and why.  Could you give us some background, as there may well be a simple way to do what you need.

Comment: In basic: i output any number between 1 and 6 images on the screen.
All images must be resized,rotated and dragged independent of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `resize()` event is only fired for the `window` - so in your case it wouldn't work on an image, regardless if it wrapped in a `div`.

There [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) which lets you use it for any element though.

Comment: i will try the plugin and post back the results. Thanks.

Comment: the plugin indeed lets me resize without the div. 
Altough it doesn't solve my initial problem. I think i will create a new question for that problem.

Thank you Rory